# I can't create a document in my couchdb database

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am new to web engineering and databases and I hope this is the right place for my question.
I am trying to create a database with couchdb but unfortunately I can't create a document with more data than the id. If the document contains just the id, then the "create document" function works.
I am really confused and do not know if I miss something.

Here is a link to a video, where I am showing my problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24X3dk1j4WM&feature=youtu.be

Thank you for any answer that could possibly help me.

Comment: The JSON is invalid, which is preventing the form from being submitted. That's not great UX, as I would expect it to print an error or something, maybe check the console.

Comment: In any case, you need a comma between each key/value pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are missing a comma. Try this:

```js
{
    "_id": "my_doc", // => notice comma
    "number": 23
}
```